# Show that the set $A = \{f\in C(X): f(x_0) = 0\}$ is a proper closed subalgebra of C(X).

Tags: real-analysis, vector-spaces, metric-spaces

Let X be a compact metric space, and let $x_0 \in X$.

*I need to show that $A = \{f\in C(X): f(x_0) = 0\}$ is a proper closed subalgebra of C(X).*

I know that an algebra is a vector space $A$ on which a multiplication is defined $(f,g)\mapsto fg$ (from $A\times A$ into $A$) satisfying:

i) $(fg) = f(gh)$, for all $f,g \in A$;

ii) $f(g + h) = fg + fh, (f + g)h = fh + gh$, for all $f,g,h \in A$;

iii) $\alpha(fg) = (\alpha f)g = f(\alpha g)$, for all scalars $\alpha$ and all $f,g \in A$.

**Question:** How do I show that $A = \{f\in C(X): f(x_0) = 0\}$ is a proper closed subalgebra of C(X)?

I really have no clue, thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you show that $A$ is a subalgebra (or even a vector subspace)? Can you show that it is closed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show that $A$ is a vector subspace of $C(X)$ it is enough to show that it is closed under taking linear combinations:

For $f, g \in A$, $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{C}$ we have:

$$(\alpha f + \beta g)(x_0) = \alpha f(x_0) + \beta g(x_0) = \alpha \cdot 0 
 + \beta \cdot 0 = 0$$

so $\alpha f + \beta g \in A$.

Now to show that $A$ is a subalgebra of $C(X)$, it suffices to prove that $A$ is closed under multiplication:

For $f, g \in A$ we have:

$$(fg)(x_0) = f(x_0)\cdot g(x_0) = 0 \cdot 0 = 0$$

so $fg \in A$.

Thus, $A$ is a subalgebra of $C(X)$.

Furthermore, $A$ is closed:

Let $\phi : C(X) \to \mathbb{C}$ be the linear map defined as $\phi(f) = f(x_0)$ for $f \in C(X)$. $\phi$ is also bounded:

$$|\phi(f)| = |f(x_0)| \le \|f\|_\infty$$
$\DeclareMathOperator{\Ker}{Ker}$
Thus, $\phi$ is continuous. We have $A = \Ker \phi$ so $A$ is closed as a preimage of a closed set by a continuous function.

Finally, $A$ is a proper subalgebra since e.g. $f \equiv 1$ is in $C(X)$ but not in $A$.